# Adding fancy page to TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, fancyhdr

I used `fancyhdr` because I need in my document a page with custom page symbol, like the following

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\cfoot{\R{א}}
```

How can I add this fancy page with the `א` as a page symbol to the table of content, such that in TOC page would appear

```
Title ....... א
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. Do you want an entry in your ToC like `א ....... p. ##` or like `Title ..... p. א`. Or you want the symbol `א` to be displayed as if it was the page number of your ToC?

Comment: @ebo, thank you for your comment. I want an entry in my TOC like Title ..... p. א

Comment: What should be the page numbering style in the main document: arabic numerals, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between page numbers set in the ToC and what you may specify in the footer (say, using [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr)). If you want a specific page number to make its way into the ToC, you need to update `\thepage`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{$\aleph$}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Title}
\begin{center}
  \Huge Title
\end{center}

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}% Reset page numbering to arabic
\tableofcontents

\chapter{A chapter}
\section{First section}
\section{Second section}
\section{Third section}
\section{Last section}

\end{document}
```

There are other methods, but this seems to be what you're after.